# TextView TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END breakStategy and wrap_content

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView whose text should align to the right side of the container. The view itself has width and height set to wrap_content, and it also has padding and a background. The problem is that if the text contains sufficiently long words that do not fit on one line and are wrapped, the TextView ends up being wider than it actually needs to be after wrapping multiple such words.

[El problemo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mlEo.jpg)

Theres code

```
private fun createTvBubbleBottom() = tvBubbleBottom ?: kotlin.run {
        val bubbleBottom = TextView(context).apply {
            id = R.id.tv_bubble
            val params = LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            )
            params.updateMargins(top = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.450))
            layoutParams = params
            textAlignment = TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END

            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_bubble)
            setTextStyle(R.style.400)
            setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Secondary))

            val marginVertical = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.400)
            val marginHorizontal = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.450)
            setPadding(marginHorizontal, marginVertical, marginHorizontal, marginVertical)
        }

        addView(bubbleBottom)
        this.tvBubbleBottom = bubbleBottom
        bubbleBottom
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code or any reference, So that it could be helpful to find solution  fast. Also check whether have you provided any padding to start.

Comment: Yes, theres padding to start, 16 dp

Comment: added code, nothing much

Comment: Try adding breakStrategy to the text view and set value to simple. And check whether it work. remember breakStrategy requires Android 9+ devices. And also try using it in different device and check whether if the problem retains!